# Waiting For long time Fetching the Data from DB

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

While Fetching the Data it seems a long time, we cant do another task during this time. am using BAckGroundWOrker for this purpose. but it seems waiting for long time after fetching all data only the application is runnig fine

```
  private void btnExrtPDF_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         btnExrtPDF.IsEnabled = false;
         Collection.Clear();                

         long NoOfRecords = 10000;
         long RecordsIcrease = 10000;
         SaveFileDialog xsfd = new SaveFileDialog()
         {
             FileName = "Book1",
             DefaultExt = ".xlsx",
             Filter = "Excel Document|*.xlsx",
             InitialDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)).ToString()
         };
         Nullable<bool> result = xsfd.ShowDialog();
         System.Data.DataTable batchFCSB = new System.Data.DataTable();
         int row = 0;
         if (result == true)
         {

             DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
             batchFCSB = DetailReportFCBuySell.ToDataTable();
             Collection.Add(row, batchFCSB);
             row = 1;
             PageIndex++;

             for (long k = NoOfRecords; k < DetailReportFCBuySell.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords; k = +NoOfRecords)
             {

                     new AlxServiceClient().Using(channel =>
                     {
                         DetailReportFCBuySell = new ObservableCollection<DLReports.FCBuySellDetail>();
                         DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
                         batchFCSB = new System.Data.DataTable();
                         batchFCSB = DetailReportFCBuySell.ToDataTable();
                         Collection.Add(row, batchFCSB);
                         row++;   

                 });
                 NoOfRecords = NoOfRecords + RecordsIcrease;
             }


             for (int k = 0; k < Collection.Keys.Count; k++)
             {
                 string xlsxFile = string.Empty;
                 xlsxFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();                    

                 TableView temp = new TableView();
                 temp.DataContext = (Collection.Where(i => i.Key == k).FirstOrDefault().Value);
                // ExportToXlsx(temp, xlsxFile);
             }
            }
m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi may I know where is the background worker invoked? this look a little bit straight by using the UI thread

Comment: m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: this is used inside this . and the methods of Background i used in constructor

Comment: Is your file opened when the application is working? I had same issue and when i closed my .xlsx file it worked fine.

Comment: @aida bigonah , i dint understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i make the editvalue to a seperate object and call that object in the thread

```
DateTime startDate =    Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date;
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date;

private DetailReportFCBuySell FetchRecord ()
{
return ObservableCollection<DLReports.FCBuySellDetail> temp = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, startDate, endDate, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code block seems like running from the beginning of the click event without invoking the BGWorker, consider to move the code block into a single function like

```
private DetailReportFCBuySell FetchRecord ()
{
    return AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
}
```

and calling this function in your m_oWorker Do Work event

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    FetchRecord();
}
```

read more on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx#code-snippet-3

Comment: its making me to wait my application for some

Comment: May I know more about the situation? Also consider use the Task in .NET, read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx